# Is it possible to filter out in Stripe API subscriptions with time in metadata?

Tags: stripe-payments, etl

I need to make an ETL that on a daily basis will download subscriptions from Stripe API that were created or changed within the past day and merge into the table.

I have a field 'updated' in metadata, it is the last update time of subscription.
And I was wondering if filteting by this 'updated' is possible in Stripe?
For example, metadata['updated'] >= 1693727314 and so on.

I found out that metadata accepts only string values without possibility to use >, <, etc.

Stripe subscription object does not contain info about modification time.
I've tried using 'updated' from metadata, but unsuccesful due to the fact that Stripe only allows ":", which is an exact match (case insensitive).

Response:
The operator `>` is not a supported search operator for field `metadata` in resource `subscriptions`. Try using one of the supported operators: `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that with just metadata unfortunately.

Ideally, you should build a webhook endpoint that can listen to subscription related events like [`customer.subscription.updated`](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#:%7E:text=customer.subscription.updated). This way, you will not have to List all Subscriptions manually but instead any updated subscription information would be delivered to you.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is possible to do using webhooks.

I have to do ETL using AirFlow and as far as I know, webhooks are pretty complicated there. Especially considering the fact that within one day there maybe thousands of subs to update.

So, I had a hope that somebody already does something related...

Comment: Just throwing it out there - if you're only working with data bundled by the day, you could just use the timecode for 00:00:00 on each day, then search for metadata for that day using `:`.

Comment: @Lucky2501 thank you! frankly, I have a hard time understanding how to implement what you have described. 
E.g. I want to get all subscriptions that were changed yesterday. Each subscription has metadata['updated']. For example, metadata['updated'] = "1692113840".
How can I search for all that were updated yesterday?

Comment: So far you've only ever talked about *days*. So I assumed you might not need hours, minutes or seconds for your routine. This means that if you updated 3 subs yesterday, you could get the timecode at time of update, and change it to set `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` to 0. Your `metadata[updated]` would then be `1695168000` (Sep 20 12AM UTC) for all 3 subs. Then, when you want to list Subscriptions updated yesterday, you only have one date to pick from, so you can use the `:` operand.